# Globally check for existence of Azure SQL Server name with AzurePowershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to get around this error message

> New-AzureRmSqlServer : 45120: The name 'server.database.windows.net' already exists. Choose a different name.

I can check for existence of a SQL Server name within a resource group, but not sure how to check globally. Yes, I could just choose a different name - but if that also exists, I would hit the same error.

Is there any way of catching the error with 'Try Catch' and doing something?? Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a do while loop ;)

```
do {
    $continue = $null
    New-AzureRmSqlServer ... -ErrorVariable continue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # Create another name here
} while ($continue)
```

Comment: Thanks,   Seems to work when adding '-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue'  - but not without.